# Insert row at the top of an excel table using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am currently working on a xlwings script to automate the process of updating a table in an excel sheet at work. I would like to insert a blank row at the top of this table. I have tried the following block of code:

`sheet.range('A5:AS5').shift('down')`

In this code, I am attempting to shift the row that exists in the range A5:AS5 down by one unit, leaving a blank row above it in the table.

However, I receive a message saying: "this won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet".

I have also tried going the api.Insert route with no luck...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'd have expected that line to return an error since 'shift' is not an attribute of the range function, it is a parameter for insert or delete. Therefore your command should be

```
sheet.range('A5:AS5').insert(shift='down')
```

Doing this should not return the error "this won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet" since it's adding the row to the sheet.

If you want/need to add a row to a table only and not to whole sheet, for example if there are other tables on the same row you don't want to add the row to also, you can emulate the Table insert row with the following;

```
sheet.range("A1").api.ListObject.ListRows.Add(4)
```

The range only needs to select a cell in the Table so it could be any cell within the range. I've used the assumed top left cell, but 'A5' may also be appropriate.
The **Add(4)** determines which row to add so **(4)** inserts new the row at row 5.
Using this method may return errors if the table expansion encroaches on the boundaries of another table or other item.